# Cartesian product of two sigma algebras

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have been working on the following problem: If we have $R = R_1\times R_2$, where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are $\sigma -algebras$, prove that $R$ is a $\sigma -algebra$ if and only if either $R_1$ or $\ R_2$ is a trivial $\sigma -algebra$ $(\{ \emptyset, X\} )$, as far as I know, this proof consists on two parts:

1. $R_1$ or $R_2$ is a trivial $\sigma -algebra$ $\implies$ $R$ is a $\sigma -algebra$

2. $R$ is a $\sigma -algebra$ $\implies$ $R_1$ or $R_2$ is a trivial $\sigma -algebra$

I have already demonstrated 1, but I am struggling on showing 2, I am trying to assume that neither $R_1$ nor $R_2$ are trivial and I am searching for a contradiction, but I don't know how to get it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Assume there are $U_i\in R_i$ ($i=1,2$) different from $\emptyset,X$, can you describe the complement to $U_1\times U_2$? is it in $R_1\times R_2$?

Comment: It is not, but it can be in another algebra different than the trivial, I think that the most difficult part is to demonstrate that the unique solution is the trivial algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a set, and let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be two $\sigma$-algebras on $X$. Assume that $R := R_1 \times R_2$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X \times X$.

For a contradiction assume that both $R_1$ and $R_2$ are nontrivial $\sigma$-algebras. Let $A \in R_1\setminus\{\emptyset, X\}$ and $B\in R_2\setminus\{\emptyset, X\}$, so $A \times B \in R$.

$R_1$ and $R_2$ are closed under complements, so $A^c \in R_1$ and $B^c \in R_2$ which means $A^c \times B^c \in R$.

$R$ is closed under finite unions, so $C \times D = (A \times B) \cup (A^c \times B^c)$ for some $C \in R_1$ and $D \in R_2$. However, notice that $A, B, A^c, B^c$ are all nonempty sets, so this equation is impossible to satisfy.